# My Blender Pan, and Move don't work WORK

Tags: interface, customization

Nothing is working, I have tried Loading the factory settings, uninstalling and re-installing, uninstalling and updating, and lots of other stuff inside of blender i also deleted all of the files located in the, "Blender Foundation" folder.